# Qt3D: Texture is black

Tags: qt, render, texture-mapping, qt3d

I'm trying to render frames captured by 3D scanner using Qt3D. Mesh is constructed right in geometry but it's shown black.
Below is my function where I convert vertices, texture coordinates, normals and add result object to a Scene. For debug purposes I'm trying to map texture from one source .png file to all the frames. But it still looks black. Normalizing texture coordinates vector didn't help.
Please take a look at my code and clarify what I'm doing wring. Thanks in advance.

```
    Qt3DCore::QEntity* object = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(parent);
    Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer* renderer = new Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer(object);
    Qt3DRender::QGeometry* geometry = new Qt3DRender::QGeometry(renderer);

    Qt3DRender::QBuffer* vertexBuffer = new Qt3DRender::QBuffer(geometry);
    Qt3DRender::QBuffer* indexBuffer = new Qt3DRender::QBuffer(geometry);

    Qt3DRender::QAttribute* positionAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute(geometry);
    Qt3DRender::QAttribute* normalAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute(geometry);
    Qt3DRender::QAttribute* texCoordAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute(geometry);
    Qt3DRender::QAttribute* indexAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute(geometry);

    const quint32 stride = (3 + 3 + 2) * sizeof(float);
    positionAttribute->setName(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::defaultPositionAttributeName());
    positionAttribute->setDataType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::Float);
    positionAttribute->setDataSize(3);
    positionAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::VertexAttribute);
    positionAttribute->setBuffer(vertexBuffer);
    positionAttribute->setByteOffset(0);
    positionAttribute->setByteStride(stride);

    normalAttribute->setName(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::defaultNormalAttributeName());
    normalAttribute->setDataType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::Float);
    normalAttribute->setDataSize(3);
    normalAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::VertexAttribute);
    normalAttribute->setBuffer(vertexBuffer);
    normalAttribute->setByteOffset(3 * sizeof(float));
    normalAttribute->setByteStride(stride);

    texCoordAttribute->setName(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::defaultTextureCoordinateAttributeName());
    texCoordAttribute->setDataType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::Float);
    texCoordAttribute->setDataSize(2);
    texCoordAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::VertexAttribute);
    texCoordAttribute->setBuffer(vertexBuffer);
    texCoordAttribute->setByteOffset((3 + 3) * sizeof(float));
    texCoordAttribute->setByteStride(stride);

    indexAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::VertexAttribute);
    indexAttribute->setDataType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::Int);
    indexAttribute->setDataSize(3);
    indexAttribute->setByteOffset(0);
    indexAttribute->setBuffer(indexBuffer);
    indexAttribute->setCount(indices.size());

    QByteArray* vertexArray = new QByteArray;
    const auto t = vertices.size();
    const auto r = sizeof(VertexData);
    const auto d = t * r;
    vertexArray->resize(vertices.size() * sizeof(VertexData));
    float* rawVertexArray = reinterpret_cast<float*>(vertexArray->data());
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); ++i)
    {
        rawVertexArray[index++] = vertices[i].position_.x();
        rawVertexArray[index++] = vertices[i].position_.y();
        rawVertexArray[index++] = vertices[i].position_.z();

        rawVertexArray[index++] = vertices[i].normal_.x();
        rawVertexArray[index++] = vertices[i].normal_.y();
        rawVertexArray[index++] = vertices[i].normal_.z();

        const auto x = vertices[i].texCoords_.x();
        rawVertexArray[index++] = vertices[i].texCoords_.x();
        const auto y = vertices[i].texCoords_.y();
        rawVertexArray[index++] = vertices[i].texCoords_.y();
    }

    QByteArray* indexArray = new QByteArray;
    indexArray->resize(indices.size() * sizeof(VertexData));

    auto* rawIndexArray = reinterpret_cast<int*>(indexArray->data());
    
    index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < indices.size(); ++i)
    {
        rawIndexArray[index++] = indices[i].x();
        rawIndexArray[index++] = indices[i].y();
        rawIndexArray[index++] = indices[i].z();
    }

    vertexBuffer->setData(*vertexArray);
    indexBuffer->setData(*indexArray);

    geometry->addAttribute(positionAttribute);
    geometry->addAttribute(normalAttribute);
    geometry->addAttribute(texCoordAttribute);
    geometry->addAttribute(indexAttribute);

    renderer->setGeometry(geometry);
    renderer->setInstanceCount(1);
    renderer->setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::TriangleFan);
    object->addComponent(renderer);

    // Texture
    Qt3DRender::QTexture2D* targetTexture = new Qt3DRender::QTexture2D(renderer);
    Qt3DRender::QTextureImage* textureImage = new Qt3DRender::QTextureImage(targetTexture);
    Qt3DExtras::QDiffuseSpecularMaterial* material = new Qt3DExtras::QDiffuseSpecularMaterial(renderer);
    //Qt3DExtras::QNormalDiffuseSpecularMapMaterial* material = new Qt3DExtras::QNormalDiffuseSpecularMapMaterial();
    textureImage->setMirrored(true);
    textureImage->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("D://Calibration tool//app-calibration-tool//output//1.jpg"));
    
    targetTexture->addTextureImage(textureImage);

   material->setDiffuse(QVariant::fromValue<Qt3DRender::QAbstractTexture *>(targetTexture));
   material->setAmbient(QColor(255, 255, 255, 1));
   material->setSpecular(QColor(255, 255, 255, 1));
   material->setTextureScale(4);
   material->setAlphaBlendingEnabled(true);

   const auto transform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(renderer);
   object->addComponent(transform);
   object->addComponent(material);

    return parent;
```

Comment: I thought of that QDiffuseSpecularMaterial doesn't support textures, only color. I tried to set orange color with setDiffuse() and my mesh became orange. 
I used QTextureMaterial but the problem is still there: black textures or no textures at all.

Comment: I don't have a solution but some suggestions: Have you tried to apply the texture to a 3D model which you can be sure of that the texture coordinates are correct? For example, you could use QSphereMesh, a Qt ready-made mesh. The texture will look skewed but this way you can be sure that your texture coordinates are wrong. It's also a good idea to provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: I've tried with the sphere  and QTextureMaterial but it says "Qt3D.Renderer.OpenGL.Backend: Unable to find suitable Texture Unit for "diffuseTexture"". Do you know why it's happening and how to influence on diffuse of this class?

Comment: Sounds like it either can't find the image you are referencing or it is broken somehow or your OpenGL version is too old. What version is it? Did you try to view the image with an image viewer? And are you sure the path to your image is correct? Maybe, as a toy example, try to load the image into a `QLabel` and display it in a simple example window.

Comment: I've updated NVidia drivers, checked openGL version installed in the system and the one my app uses. It's 466.47. This doesn't seem to be a problem. 
I've also loaded image as a QLabel and it looks good and appears on screen. 
But the point that I used QPixMap to pass it to QLabel but in my render window QTextureImage is used.

Comment: UPDATE: I succeeded in mapping texture on QSphereMesh using draw() method of my custom image class derived from QPaintedTextureImage. But for my geometry it still lack of diffuseTexture (Unable to find suitable Texture Unit for "diffuseTexture")

Comment: One more update. I used QPaintedTextureImage class instead of QTextureImage and textures are mapped correctly on QT mesh and on my custom geometry from file. Now I'm trying to convert my custom itexture image to QPaintedTextureImage and pass it to render. Thank you for your ideas, they really helped!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) You could check out [this](https://github.com/florianblume/simpleqml3d) example and replace the 3D model and texture with your own and see if that works. Maybe that helps you on fixing your `QTextureImage` issue.